# Proxy Config for apt - Excluding Whole Subnets

Tags: apt, proxy

When apt is configured to use a proxy it is possible to bypass the proxy for certain IPs using the "DIRECT" keyword.

For example:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy::"10.10.10.1" "DIRECT";
```

Is there a way to do this for a subnet range?

Simply using a CIDR like this does not appear to work:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy::"10.10.10.0/24" "DIRECT";
```